# Fourth moment of a stationary GARCH process

Tags: probability-theory, time-series, stationary-processes

I have a martingale difference series $(Z_t)$ with respect to a given filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t)$, i.e. $E[Z_t \mid \mathcal{F}_{t-1}] = 0$. Furthermore, $E[Z_t^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_{t-1}] = 1$. I also have a process
$$\sigma_t^2 = \alpha + \phi\sigma_{t-1}^2 + \theta X_{t-1}^2$$
and
$$X_t = \sigma_t Z_t$$
We have $\sigma_t$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F}_{t-1}$. Now suppose $(X_t)$ is a stationary process. Then, 
$$E[X_t^2\mid\mathcal{F}_{t-1}] = E[\sigma_t^2Z_t^2\mid\mathcal{F}_{t-1}]=\sigma_t^2E[Z_t^2\mid\mathcal{F}_{t-1}] = \sigma_t^2$$
Hence, $E[X_t^2] = E[\sigma_t^2]$. Since $X_t$ is stationary and has zero mean, $E[X_t^2]$ and therefore, $E[\sigma_t^2]$ is independent of $t$.

Is it then also true that $E[\sigma_t^4]$ is independent of $t$?

Comment: The answer depends on the behaviour of the sequence of general term $E(Z_t^4)$. Any hypothesis on this?

Comment: @Did I think it is safe to assume that $Z_t$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_{t-1}$ and that the fourth order moments exist.

Comment: ?? You mean $(Z_t)$ independent?

Comment: @Did The filtration is not necessarily the natural one. Since $(Z_t)$ is adapted, it is an independent sequence for sure. But perhaps leaving the filtration arbitrary brings something new to the table. The lecture notes I am following doesn't always explicitly state the assumptions. Perhaps the author has an iid sequence in mind here for $(Z_t)$. But feel free to impose any conditions compatible with the ones in the question without reducing the problem to something trivial.

Comment: @Did I think I figured how to do this. The stationary solution of a GARCH equation, if it exists, is unique. I have an expression for that in terms of an infinite sum of cumulative products. It is a lot of bookkeeping but it gives the answer I think.